# Sorting Worksheet data by custom lists using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I want to sort a column in a sheet using values in another column(which is in another sheet).

For example, the values are in the column are "abc", "def" and "ghi". These values are in a column of the first sheet, but the values of the column are jumbled up. I want them sorted such that the values are in the order of "abc","def" and "ghi".

I tried this for example:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("G").Sort key1:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D:D"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes.
```

There is an error when I do so:

```
The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.
```

Not sure what's the error. Need some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a macro you can just use the below formula and get the records sorted.

```
=MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0)
```